# What do spacecraft travel paths in The Expanse look like?

Tags: space, physics, the-expanse-2015, the-expanse-novels

In [The Expanse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Expanse_(novel_series)), spacecraft use magical technology called [Epstein Drives](http://www.syfy.com/theexpanse/drive/) to travel at [constant 1g acceleration](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/840/how-fast-will-1g-get-you-there) (and deceleration), subject to real world physical constraints. This is in contrast to the current approach of traveling at essentially 0g (between [maneuvers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN5lU.png)).

I understand that the current approach results in travel paths that are essentially (solar) orbits (at least for interplanetary distances); and I understand basically what constraints that places on what travel paths must look like.

Since these (real world) constraints apply to the in-world physics of flight paths in The Expanse, I wonder what real world physics has to say about what flight paths in The Expanse look like.

---

All I've found is one relatively old and unhelpful [post on Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/38178/2540). But it's unclear from that whether it resents a general form for travel paths.

Comment: [Space travel using constant acceleration drive: Earth to Europa](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3897/space-travel-using-constant-acceleration-drive-earth-to-europa) - Basically you can use the point'n'shoot method if energy consumption isn't an issue.

Comment: Relevant meta discussion; [Science Fiction - Scientific Basis/Accuracy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10105/science-fiction-scientific-basis-accuracy)

Answer (score 3):

From the visual information we are given, which isn't a lot, we can see flattish curves as would be expected and some almost S shapes (as indicated in your question).

Pretty much the only representation is from Season 1, Episode 5 *"Back to the Butcher"* when Miller is checking the flightpaths of the *Scopuli* or *Anubis*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Part of the question is whether those would be accurate representations of 1g spaceflight trajectories.

Comment: I'm asking whether there are "generalizations ... can be made about what a constant 1g travel path looks like".

Comment: The technology is magical. The resulting physics of a constant 1g path are not.

Comment: That's the point: the physics of The Expanse are real, so to know what the paths of spacecraft in that world look like, I need to ask a question about real physics (incorporating the fictional premise of the technology).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius - Questions about whether they're *real-world accurate* are [off-topic](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10105/science-fiction-scientific-basis-accuracy). What they look like in-universe is on-topic.

Comment: @Valorum: Yes, that's the question. And given that they're meant to be real-world accurate, the question becomes: what does a real-world 1g path look like.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius - That's a question for Space:SE, not Scifi:SE.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius - Which would be off-topic, as decided in our [current policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7367/51379) on science questions. Asking whether something is “accurate” or could “really work” is off-topic. It did happen on the show. What we can ask on this site is what the paths looked like. It would be fine to mention what they “should” look like in an answer, but that can’t really be the basis of a question. It would tend to to solicit answers based entirely on orbital mechanics, without a hint of connection to the actual series.

Comment: @Adamant: Maybe you're not familiar with the show and the books, but a fundamental aspect of both (as well as much of the enthusiasm about them) is that the in-world physics are real world physics (at least for space travel). The only way to answer the question about how spacecraft in-world travel, is by answering a real world physics question. You're probably right (I'm kinda convinced on this point) that I won't get a good answer here; but the question is on-topic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44650/discussion-between-adamant-and-raxacoricofallapatorius).